# RESTful API не могу отправить данные через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, http, header, cross-domain

Есть сервер, который принимает запросы, с `GET` и `POST` все нормально, принимает. Когда отправляю `PUT` и `DELETE` запросы, через `ajax` выскакивает ошибка js:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://***.***/users/get. Method PUT
>   is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

В файле `index.php` на самом начале поставил `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`, ничего не помогает. 
Сам `ajax` запрос:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: 'http://***.***/users/get',
  data: {"data": "mydata"},
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (data) {
  }
});
```

Везде где читал об этом пишут написать в `php` файле код `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`, но это мне не помогает.

Подскажите что делать?

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Оно же Вам человеческим языком сообщает, что проблема в `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, а не в `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке ведь сказано, что `PUT` Вам не хватает для полного счастья. Вам необходимо хедер добавить для поддержки этого метода. Сразу дам совет: префлайт запросы часто отсылаются методом OPTIONS, поэтому позаботьтесь о том, чтобы такой запрос дошел до строчки, которая хэдер этот выводит:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

Почитать на русском про кросс-доменные AJAX можно [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain).